# Component which can take a collection and render it without any markup

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is there a JSF component which can take a collection of items and render it the way I want? Like a `h:dataTable`, but then without the markup of a HTML `<table>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Facelets, use `<ui:repeat>`.

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
...
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
    #{item}<br />
<ui:repeat>
```

Or when you're still on legacy JSP, use JSTL `<c:forEach>`.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:forEach items="#{bean.list}" var="item">
    #{item}<br />
</c:forEach>
```